# ObjectQuery.Include() => ObjectQuery.IncludeAll()

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

The following example retrieves a set of related entities when customers are queried.  Where can I find a sample that recursively walks the relationship graph and includes them all automatically?

```
using(Entities context = new Entities())
{
    return context.Customers
        .Include("Address")
        .Include("Address.State")
        .Include("Address.State.Country")
        .Include("Phone")
        .Include("Phone.PhoneType").Single(c => c.LastName.StartsWith("Jo");
}
```

vs.

```
using(Entities context = new Entities())
{
    return context.Customers.IncludeAll().Single(c => c.LastName.StartsWith("Jo");
}
```

Comment: Having such a method is dangerous. You may end up loading whole database.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
context.Customers.Include(c => c.Address.State.Country)
                 .Include(c => c.Phone.PhoneType)
                 .Single(c => c.LastName.StartsWith("Jo");
```

You don't want include all as not in all cases you need everything.